# What is the official way to get some style into a Launchpad-app?

Tags: css, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a maybe stupid question. I have an app that runs in the launchpad. When running it from WebIDE, my `style.css` file is loaded and everything works fine. When I run it from the launchpad, the css-file is empty.
In SDK I found :

> Caution!
> As stated in the Compatibility Rules, the HTML and CSS generated by SAPUI5 is not part of the public API and may change in patch and minor releases. If you decide to override styles, you have the obligation to test and update your modifications each time SAPUI5 is updated. **A prerequisite for this is that you have control over the version of SAPUI5 being used, for example in a standalone scenario. This is not possible when running your app in the SAP Fiori launchpad where SAPUI5 is centrally loaded for all apps. As such, SAP Fiori launchpad apps should not override styles.**

Does that mean, that I can not use my css-file in the app that should run in Launchpad? What is the official way to get some style into a launchpad-app?

**In addition:**

I embedded it in manifest: `"resources": { "css": [ { "uri": "css/style.css" } ] },`

and in Component.js:

```
        manifest: "json",
        includes : [ "css/shell.css", "css/style.css" ]
        // includes : [ "css/shell.css" ] 
    },

    /**
     * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
     * @public
     * @override
     */
    init: function () {

        jQuery.sap.includeStyleSheet(sap.ui.resource("op/VA_Splitapp_op", "css/style.css"));
```

Do I need to embed it at another place?

Comment: Did you try using UI5/THEME_DESIGNER transaction in frontend system? You can control CSS for launchpad from there. (reference: https://blog.sap-press.com/sap-fiori-launchpad-customization)

Comment: I would also recommend the theme designer, but you should still be able to load a custom CSS file per app. How do you embed your CSS?